# Problem with timing and mouse_event moving small increments

Tags: c++, timer, mouseevent

The issue I'm having is that the loop that moves my mouse only works if I introduce a 5ms delay for example. The only problem is I can't afford to do this because my function has to be precise as hell. I have verified all the calculations and made sure everything in hindsight should work, the x,y that are put in as arguments are equal to the movedx and movedy at the end of the function meaning calculations are indeed correct . But I'm still itching my head as to why it doesn't work. If I had to guess it would have to be that the values are too small to pass into mouse_event. I'm not quite sure, before coming here I've tried a few of the solutions that chatGPT brought up but I have had no luck.

It's important to note that I can not change the increments that the mouse moves nor the time it takes to move as otherwise it wouldn't be effective for my "game scripts".

I will include my timer class for context but if any of you guys need a good timer class it is 0.1ms precise for a cost of around 5% CPU Usage but I assume that varies on specs.

the timer class used in the function

```
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer()
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&starting_time);
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    }

    double Elapsed()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER current_time;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&current_time);
        double elapsed = static_cast<double>(current_time.QuadPart - starting_time.QuadPart) /
            static_cast<double>(frequency.QuadPart) * 1000.0;
        return elapsed;
    }

private:
    LARGE_INTEGER starting_time;
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
};
```

my mouse event function, the scaled variables are to tune the mouse movements to the sens in game.

```
void mouse_move_event(float x, float y)
{
    int scaledX = x / (-0.03f * 0.35f * 3.0f * (90.0f / 100.0f));
    int scaledY = y / (-0.03f * 0.35f * 3.0f * (90.0f / 100.0f));

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, scaledX, scaledY, 0, 0);
}
```

the lerp function

```
float lerp(float start, float end, float t) {
    return start + t * (end - start);
}
the lerpMouse function i made that doesnt necessarily work
void lerpMouse(float x, float y, float time)
{
    Timer timer;
    float elapsed = timer.Elapsed();
    float movedx = 0, movedy = 0;
    while (elapsed < time)
    {
        float t = elapsed / time;
        float lerpx = lerp(0, x, t);
        float lerpy = lerp(0, y, t);
        float movex = lerpx - movedx;
        float movey = lerpy - movedy;
        mouse_move_event(movex, movey);
        movedx = lerpx;
        movedy = lerpy;
        elapsed = timer.Elapsed();
    }
    mouse_move_event(x - movedx, y - movedy);
}
```

```
{0.000000,-2.257792}
```

this is an example of the first value  x,y that I put into lerp mouse, if I had to guess it's been divided and therefore is too small to move. But I've only been coding C++ for a couple of months and am definitely am no pro but that would be my best guess.

Any help or insight is heavily appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some more input on how lerpMouse is used and the calls that you are expecting to mouse_event? It looks like you don't yield to the system and  then there will not be any new mouse movement to process. Do you have to put in relative coordinates? The `x - movedx` and `y-movedy` kills precision, so you can't just accumulate up them again to get the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

here's my c++ code for moving the mouse and clicking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
   Sleep(500);
   
    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
      
      POINT pnt;
      GetCursorPos(&pnt);

      int beginning_y_axis = pnt.y; 
      int beginning_x_axis =  pnt.x;

      if(  ((beginning_x_axis >= 550 && beginning_x_axis <= 600) || (beginning_x_axis <= 650 && beginning_x_axis >= 600) ) &&
           ((beginning_y_axis >= 250 && beginning_y_axis <= 300) || (beginning_y_axis <= 350 && beginning_y_axis >= 300) )         )
      {
          // left mouse button down
         INPUT in;
         ZeroMemory(&in, sizeof(in)); // ZeroMemory fills a block of memory with zeros. 
         in.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
         in.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

         SendInput(1, &in, sizeof(INPUT)); // the 1 means theres only one thing happening thats the mouse button down
      }
        
      std::cout << "x: " << beginning_x_axis << " y: " << beginning_y_axis << std::endl;

      /*************************/
      // 600 is a magical number i used it for demonstration example, replace with target x axis

      if (beginning_x_axis == 600 || beginning_x_axis == 601 || beginning_x_axis == 599)
      {
         beginning_x_axis = beginning_x_axis;
      }
      else if (beginning_x_axis < 600)
      {
         beginning_x_axis += 2;
      }
      else if (beginning_x_axis > 600)
      {
         beginning_x_axis -= 2;
      }

      /*************************/
      // 300 is magical number, i used it for demonstration example, replace with target y axis

      if (beginning_y_axis == 300 || beginning_y_axis == 301 || beginning_y_axis == 299)
      {
         beginning_y_axis = beginning_y_axis;
      }
      else if (beginning_y_axis < 300)
      {
         beginning_y_axis += 2;
      }
      else if (beginning_y_axis > 300)
      {
         beginning_y_axis -= 2;
      }

      /*************************/

      SetCursorPos(beginning_x_axis, beginning_y_axis);
      std::cout << "x: " << beginning_x_axis << " y: " << beginning_y_axis << std::endl;
        
      
         // left mouse button up
         INPUT out;

         ZeroMemory(&out, sizeof(out)); // ZeroMemory fills a block of memory with zeros. 
         out.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
         out.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
         SendInput(1, &out, sizeof(INPUT)); // the 1 means theres only one thing happening thats the mouse button up
      
      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you see i move the mouse twice. in the if conditions where i mention magical numbers. maybe you use numbers that don't work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34850862)